# Unity error "Internal build system error. Backend exited with code -1073740791." has Destroyed/Killed my Project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok I might be over Exaggerating here but it's true, the project is broken due to error when I start opening it "Internal build system error. Backend exited with code -1073740791".The app of
this Project has already been released on Google Play, maybe there is something to do with the settings? Can Please Anyone Help?

The Full Error:

```
Internal build system error. Backend exited with code -1073740791.
STDOUT:
[   0s] Delete 9 artifact files that are no longer in use. (like Library\Bee\artifacts\movedfrom\Unity.VisualScripting.Antlr3.Runtime.dll_2086064903115821086.movedfrom)
[ 80/296  0s] MovedFromExtractor Library/Bee/artifacts/movedfrom/Unity.VisualScripting.IonicZip.dll_2325611340324208551.movedfrom
[ 81/296  0s] MovedFromExtractor Library/Bee/artifacts/movedfrom/Unity.VisualScripting.YamlDotNet.dll_640181916459675141.movedfrom
[ 82/297  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/UnityEngine.UI.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[ 83/299  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/UnityEngine.TestRunner.rsp
[ 84/299  1s] MovedFromExtractor Library/Bee/artifacts/movedfrom/Unity.Plastic.Antlr3.Runtime.dll_5744707985310546343.movedfrom
[ 89/302  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/UnityEditor.TestRunner.rsp
[ 90/304  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/UnityEngine.UI.rsp
[ 91/304  1s] MovedFromExtractor Library/Bee/artifacts/movedfrom/Unity.Plastic.Newtonsoft.Json.dll_2125035100625013150.movedfrom
[ 92/305  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/UnityEditor.UI.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[ 93/307  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/UnityEditor.UI.rsp
[ 94/308  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/AstarPathfindingProject.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[ 95/309  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/PsdPlugin.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[ 96/310  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.Animation.Triangle.Runtime.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[ 97/311  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.Common.Runtime.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[ 98/312  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.IK.Runtime.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[ 99/313  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.Path.Editor.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[100/314  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.PixelPerfect.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[101/315  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.Sprite.Editor.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[102/316  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.Tilemap.Editor.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[103/317  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.Tilemap.Extras.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[104/318  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.CollabProxy.Editor.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[105/319  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.InternalAPIEngineBridge.001.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[106/320  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.Mathematics.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[107/321  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.Mobile.AndroidLogcat.Editor.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[108/322  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.Notifications.Android.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[109/323  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.Notifications.iOS.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[110/324  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[112/326  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.TextMeshPro.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[113/327  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.Timeline.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[114/328  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.VSCode.Editor.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[115/329  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.VisualScripting.Core.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[118/332  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/UnityEngine.Advertisements.Editor.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[119/333  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/UnityEngine.Advertisements.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[120/334  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/PackageToolsEditor.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[121/336  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.Common.Runtime.rsp
[122/338  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.InternalAPIEngineBridge.001.rsp
[123/340  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.Mathematics.rsp
[124/341  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.Animation.Runtime.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[125/343  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.Sprite.Editor.rsp
[126/344  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.Common.Editor.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[127/346  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.PixelPerfect.rsp
[128/347  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.PixelPerfect.Editor.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[129/348  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.SpriteShape.Runtime.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[130/350  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.Tilemap.Editor.rsp
[131/352  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.Tilemap.Extras.rsp
[132/353  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.Tilemap.Extras.Editor.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[133/354  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.InternalAPIEditorBridge.001.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[134/355  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.Mathematics.Editor.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[135/357  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.Notifications.Android.rsp
[136/359  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.Notifications.iOS.rsp
[137/360  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.Notifications.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[138/362  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.TextMeshPro.rsp
[139/363  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.TextMeshPro.Editor.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[140/365  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.Timeline.rsp
[141/366  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.Timeline.Editor.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[142/368  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.VisualScripting.Core.rsp
[143/369  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.VisualScripting.Core.Editor.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[144/370  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.VisualScripting.Flow.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[145/372  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/UnityEngine.Advertisements.rsp
[146/373  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/UnityEngine.Monetization.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[147/374  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/AstarPathfindingProjectEditor.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[148/376  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.Animation.Runtime.rsp
[149/378  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.Animation.Triangle.Runtime.rsp
[150/380  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.Common.Editor.rsp
[151/382  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.InternalAPIEditorBridge.001.rsp
[152/383  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.Animation.Editor.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[153/385  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.Path.Editor.rsp
[154/387  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.SpriteShape.Runtime.rsp
[155/388  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.SpriteShape.Editor.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[156/390  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.VisualScripting.Core.Editor.rsp
[157/392  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.VisualScripting.Flow.rsp
[158/393  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.VisualScripting.Flow.Editor.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[159/394  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.VisualScripting.State.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[160/396  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.Animation.Editor.rsp
[161/398  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.IK.Runtime.rsp
[162/399  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.IK.Editor.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[163/400  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.Psdimporter.Editor.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[164/402  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.VisualScripting.Flow.Editor.rsp
[165/404  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.VisualScripting.State.rsp
[166/405  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.VisualScripting.State.Editor.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[167/406  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/VSSettingsProvider.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[168/408  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.IK.Editor.rsp
[169/410  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.PixelPerfect.Editor.rsp
[170/414  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/PsdPlugin.rsp
[171/414  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.Psdimporter.Editor.rsp
[172/416  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.SpriteShape.Editor.rsp
[173/418  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.Tilemap.Extras.Editor.rsp
[174/420  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.Mathematics.Editor.rsp
[175/422  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.Mobile.AndroidLogcat.Editor.rsp
[176/424  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.Notifications.rsp
[177/426  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.rsp
[178/428  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.Rider.Editor.rsp
[179/430  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.TextMeshPro.Editor.rsp
[180/432  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.Timeline.Editor.rsp
[181/434  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.VSCode.Editor.rsp
[182/436  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.VisualScripting.State.Editor.rsp
[183/438  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.VisualStudio.Editor.rsp
[184/440  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/UnityEngine.Advertisements.Editor.rsp
[185/442  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/UnityEngine.Monetization.rsp
[186/443  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Assembly-CSharp.dll.movedfrom.rsp
[187/445  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/AstarPathfindingProject.rsp
[188/447  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.CollabProxy.Editor.rsp
[189/449  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/UnityEngine.Advertisements.DevX.Editor.rsp
[190/451  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/PackageToolsEditor.rsp
[191/453  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/AstarPathfindingProjectEditor.rsp
[192/455  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/VSSettingsProvider.rsp
[193/457  0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Assembly-CSharp.rsp
[196/457  3s] Csc Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/UnityEngine.TestRunner.dll (+2 others)
[197/457  0s] CopyTool Library/ScriptAssemblies/UnityEngine.TestRunner.pdb
[198/457  0s] CopyTool Library/ScriptAssemblies/UnityEngine.TestRunner.dll
[199/457  0s] MovedFromExtractor Library/Bee/artifacts/movedfrom/UnityEngine.TestRunner.ref.dll_8368799695770714308.movedfrom
[200/457  3s] Csc Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/UnityEngine.UI.dll (+2 others)
[201/457  0s] CopyTool Library/ScriptAssemblies/UnityEngine.UI.pdb
[203/457  0s] CopyTool Library/ScriptAssemblies/UnityEngine.UI.dll
[204/457  0s] MovedFromExtractor Library/Bee/artifacts/movedfrom/UnityEngine.UI.ref.dll_13680447769613716870.movedfrom
[205/457  2s] Csc Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/UnityEditor.TestRunner.dll (+2 others)
[208/457  0s] CopyTool Library/ScriptAssemblies/UnityEditor.TestRunner.dll
[209/457  0s] CopyTool Library/ScriptAssemblies/UnityEditor.TestRunner.pdb
[210/457  1s] Csc Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/UnityEditor.UI.dll (+2 others)
[219/457  4s] Csc Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.Tilemap.Editor.dll (+2 others)
[220/457  4s] Csc Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/AstarPathfindingProject.dll (+2 others)
[220/457  0s] CopyTool Library/ScriptAssemblies/Unity.2D.Tilemap.Editor.pdb
[222/457  0s] CopyTool Library/ScriptAssemblies/Unity.2D.Tilemap.Editor.dll
[223/457  3s] Csc Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.Common.Runtime.dll (+2 others)
[224/457  0s] CopyTool Library/ScriptAssemblies/AstarPathfindingProject.pdb
[225/457  0s] CopyTool Library/ScriptAssemblies/AstarPathfindingProject.dll
[226/457  0s] CopyTool Library/ScriptAssemblies/Unity.2D.Common.Runtime.dll
[229/457  5s] Csc Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.dll (+2 others)
[231/457  0s] MovedFromExtractor Library/Bee/artifacts/movedfrom/Unity.2D.Common.Runtime.ref.dll_17822817306688496483.movedfrom
[232/457  0s] CopyTool Library/ScriptAssemblies/Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.pdb
[239/457  0s] CopyTool Library/ScriptAssemblies/Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.dll
[240/457  2s] Csc Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.Notifications.iOS.dll (+2 others)
[241/457  2s] Csc Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.Tilemap.Extras.dll (+2 others)
[242/457  0s] CopyTool Library/ScriptAssemblies/Unity.Notifications.iOS.pdb
[243/457  2s] Csc Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.Notifications.Android.dll (+2 others)
[244/457  0s] CopyTool Library/ScriptAssemblies/Unity.2D.Tilemap.Extras.dll
[245/457  0s] CopyTool Library/ScriptAssemblies/Unity.Notifications.Android.dll
[246/457  0s] CopyTool Library/ScriptAssemblies/Unity.Notifications.Android.pdb
[248/457  2s] Csc Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.Animation.Triangle.Runtime.dll (+2 others)
[249/457  0s] MovedFromExtractor Library/Bee/artifacts/movedfrom/Unity.Notifications.Android.ref.dll_15514552198952893227.movedfrom
[250/457  0s] MovedFromExtractor Library/Bee/artifacts/movedfrom/Unity.2D.Tilemap.Extras.ref.dll_13185418342785991921.movedfrom
[251/457  0s] MovedFromExtractor Library/Bee/artifacts/movedfrom/Unity.2D.Animation.Triangle.Runtime.ref.dll_17903118484747357354.movedfrom
[252/457  0s] CopyTool Library/ScriptAssemblies/Unity.2D.Animation.Triangle.Runtime.dll
[253/457  0s] CopyTool Library/ScriptAssemblies/Unity.2D.Animation.Triangle.Runtime.pdb
[254/457  0s] CopyTool Library/ScriptAssemblies/Unity.Notifications.iOS.dll
[259/457  1s] Csc Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.Notifications.dll (+2 others)
[261/457  0s] MovedFromExtractor Library/Bee/artifacts/movedfrom/Unity.Notifications.iOS.ref.dll_8642665151043550249.movedfrom
[262/457  0s] CopyTool Library/ScriptAssemblies/Unity.Notifications.dll
[264/457  2s] Csc Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.Rider.Editor.dll (+2 others)
[266/457  0s] CopyTool Library/ScriptAssemblies/Unity.Rider.Editor.dll
[267/457  2s] Csc Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.Sprite.Editor.dll (+2 others)
[269/457  0s] CopyTool Library/ScriptAssemblies/Unity.Rider.Editor.pdb
[270/457  0s] CopyTool Library/ScriptAssemblies/Unity.2D.Sprite.Editor.pdb
[271/457  1s] Csc Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.2D.IK.Runtime.dll (+2 others)
[276/457  0s] CopyTool Library/ScriptAssemblies/Unity.2D.Sprite.Editor.dll
[277/457  2s] Csc Library/Bee/artifacts/1300b0aE.dag/Unity.VisualStudio.Editor.dll (+2 others)
[278/457  0s] CopyTool Library/ScriptAssemblies/Unity.2D.IK.Runtime.dll
STDERR:
tundra: error: Couldn't launch process
errno: 2 (No such file or directory) GetLastError: 5 (0x00000005): Access is denied.
```

Additional Errors:

```
1. 

(Why is number 1 is blank? it's because it is, Its in the error log)

> 2.Library\ScriptAssemblies\Unity.2D.Common.Runtime.pdb: 

3.Library\ScriptAssemblies\Unity.2D.Tilemap.Extras.pdb: 

4.Library\ScriptAssemblies\Unity.Notifications.pdb:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Back up everything now in case anything you try makes things worse. If you have any previous backups be sure to keep them safe. While
   unlikely, if it turned out the issues were caused by drive trouble it could be that the drive is on the verge of failing.
2. After having backed everything up, try closing Unity and then deleting the Library\Bee folder from your project directory. Hopefully your problem is now solved.

...

3. If your problem was not solved: try deleting or moving the following folders and files from your project folder:

- .vs
- Library
- obj
- Temp
- UserSettings
- .vsconfig
- *.csproj
- *.sln

Basically everything **except** Assets, Packages, and ProjectSettings (unless you added any custom files or folders to the root folder manually, though even if so you just backed them up a moment ago right?)

4. If your Unity project directory is under an unusual or long full directory name e.g. `C:\Users\Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch\Documents\Unity Projects\UnityProject` or `C:\Users\JokūbasØy̸̧̓ṽ̴͉̬̰̌͘ì̷͓ṋ̶̮̓͊͝d̴̢̫͉͋\Documents\UnityProject`, try moving it somewhere simpler like `C:\Unity\UnityProject`.
5. Restart your PC. You can never be too certain of what problems might potentially be fixed by turning it off and on again.
6. Load the project into Unity and pray it imports successfully this time.

If none of that works: If you updated Unity immediately before the problem began, reinstall the older version and try the above steps again. If that fails too, trying a newer Unity version in desperation would not be unreasonable. Probably the Bee folder thing solved your problem and you never got here though.

Comment: Number 4 worked! Thanks Sven Viking. I never thought to restart my laptop.

Comment: Great! Just adding for anyone else reading that I edited the answer within seconds of your comment and #4 is now #5.

Answer (score 1):

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 this worked for me:

- Open in safe mode then exit safe mode without fixing anything
- Go to `Library/Bee/` and delete the `TundraBuildState.state.map`
- Press the play button and the game starts. The deleted file is also rebuilt.

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

You could try turning off your anti-virus software.  That solved the problem when I started having it out of the blue.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue that created bunch of stupid errors in the Unity Console BUT I have **Solved it** by:

1. First question if you have moved your project anywhere: Example: Changed the initial location of it - meaning when you first created it, have you changed **Project Folder name** or **Moved it to different location**?
2. If so, please look into the errors you have in your Unity Console (Not all of them makes sense) but one will: We're looking for previous name of your Unity Project Folder and its' initial location.
3. As you find it please rename folder to one found in **Unity Console Error** and/or move it to **Unity Console Error** location

Hope that helps.
That will solve more than one error in your Unity Console