# Unity error: Internal build system error. Backend exited with code 2. tundra: error: Unexpected stdin

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I am getting this error when I modified one file(any file that belong to the asset aimfluent chatbot) after running the application. It won't appear when I am editing other file except aimfluent asset scripts (I am not using firebase). I am using 2021.3.13f1 unity version (windows).

`Internal build system error. Backend exited with code 2. tundra: error: Unexpected stdin`

I have tried several solutions available ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71750529/unity-error-internal-build-system-error-backend-exited-with-code-1073740791)) such as deleting Library/Bee folder, deleting Library folder, restarting, deleting RAV antivirus, etc. However still I am getting this error and couldn't develop my game.
When I try to build the project it shows this error,

```
Internal build system error. Backend exited with code 2.

STDOUT:

Finished compiling graph: 519 nodes, 6427 flattened edges (6427 ToBuild, 0 ToUse), maximum node priority 200

STDERR:

tundra: error: Unexpected stdin
```

I have been looking for a solution to this for 2 days. Appreciate if anyone can help me to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. Apparently, it's caused by Firebase.
this fixed it for me
[firebase-unity-sdk-editor-python-fix](https://github.com/techyworm10/firebase-unity-sdk-editor-python-fix)

Answer (score 0):

For me there was a issue in SDK networks at editor level which was causing this issue. My firebase was not getting connected with Python. I just update all the SDKs to latest and resolve all the issues not this error is gone.